# Existe algum jeito de checar se um numero de celular é valido?

Tags: php, javascript

Procurei em sites de buscas e não encontrei nada que pudesse ajudar; eu precisava impedir que números residenciais fosse digitados no input o ideal seria usar apenas javascript para isso.

Comment: Dá pra fazer, olhe por exemplo esse site: http://www.qualoperadora.net, ele faz exatamente isso, mas não tenho certeza do trabalho que da pra fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Bom, regex não é o meu forte. Mas tentei algo para você aqui, segui o seguinte padrão:

- O valor inserido pelo usuário deve começar com 8 ou 9 - `^[9|8]`;
- Deve ser seguido apenas por números - `\d`;
- Deve ter um tamanho minimo de 7 dígitos e máximo de 8 - `{7,8}`;

E este foi o regex que fiz para validar o que falei acima: `/^[9|8]\d{7,8}/g`

---

### Exemplo

CSS (Apenas para deixar a borda vermelha...)

```
/* Só para remover o outline */
input.phone-number:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input.phone-number.invalid {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

HTML (Um formulário básico)

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="tel" class="phone-number" autofocus="true" placeholder="Digite um número de celular" maxlength="9">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
// Quando o DOM estiver pronto;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Pega o input do telefone;
    var phone = document.querySelector('.phone-number');

    // Detecta quando o formulário for enviado;
    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(evt) {

        // Se não passar na validação do regex;
        if(!phone.value.match(/^[9|8]\d{7,8}/g)) {
            phone.classList.add('invalid');
        }

        // Se passar na validação do regex;
        else {
            // Envia o formulário caso seja valido
            return true;
        }

        // Falso por padrão para que o formulário só seja enviado caso seja válido;
        return false;
    };

}, false);
```

No caso detecto quando o formulário for enviado com a função `onsubmit();` e deixo um `return false;` como padrão, apenas para que o formulário só seja enviado caso seja válido;

Caso o número não seja válido eu adiciono a classe `.invalid` para o `input.phone-number`;

Do contrário eu permito o envio do formulário...

### @Edit

Fiz uma pequena função para você aqui, veja se ajuda em algo:

```
;(function(window, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    function phoneNumber(params) {
        if(!(this instanceof phoneNumber)) {
            return new phoneNumber(params);
        };

        this.element = params;
    }

    phoneNumber.prototype = {

        check: function(callback, error) {

            var oThis = this,
                oReturn = false;

            [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(this.element)).forEach(function(element){
                if(element.value.match(/^\d{2}[8|9]\d{7,8}/g)) {
                    if(callback) callback();
                    oReturn = true;
                }
                else {
                    if(error) error();
                };
            });

            return oReturn;
        }

    };

    window.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

}(window));
```

Você pode criar um arquivo `.js` e inserir no seu documento da mesma forma que faria com o jQuery por exemplo;

```
<script src="nomedocript.js"></script>
```

E então pode usar da seguinte maneira:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var oPhone = document.querySelector('.phone-number');

    oPhone.oninput = function() {

        phoneNumber('.phone-number').check(function() {
            oPhone.classList.remove('invalid');
            oPhone.classList.add('valid');
        }, function() {
            oPhone.classList.remove('valid');
            oPhone.classList.add('invalid');
        });


    };

});
```

A função `phoneNumber('SELETOR DO ELEMENTO QUE QUER VALIDAR')` é o que criei para você usar, você deve chamar o método `.check()`, então ele vai retornar `true` ou `false` para `value()` do input que você estiver usando;

Veja:

```
// Retorna true para 15954418200;
// Mas false para 123
phoneNumber('.phone-number').check();
```

Caso você queira usar um callback (como no exemplo), basta passar eles como funções dentro do método `check()`, veja:

```
phoneNumber('.phone-number').check(function() {
    // Callback para sucesso
}, function() {
    // Callback para erro
});
```

Infelizmente, devido a portabilidade não é possível verificar qual a operadora de um número apenas pelo número em si. Se quiser validar isso, vai ter que usar um outro sistema, talvez até tenha que trabalhar com requisições `AJAX` para sistemas já prontos; O @Math deixou como comentário da sua pergunta um desses serviços, vai de você verificar qual é o melhor para se usar...

Comment: Posso ter cometido algum equivoco, mas como falei regex não é meu forte; Tentei ajudar.

Comment: Já vi que vai ser muito complicado para não dizer impossível, além do número teria que verificar o DD. Mas obrigada por tentar ajudar vou ver o que posso fazer aqui mas estou quase desistindo da ideia.

Comment: @Rose, qual é o padrão dos números que usa em seu input? Seria algo assim: (00) 0000-0000 ?

Comment: Olha só na verdade eu queria que nesse campo só aceitasse números da OI, TIM, VIVO e CLARO... mas hoje já não consigo pensar em mais nada. ~)

Comment: @Rose, sim, da para fazer isso; Mas o que quero saber, é como o usuário deve digitar esse número? Por exemplo, ele chega no input e pode inserir o número assim: 41 0000 0000, ou ele deve digitar já com os parenteses e o hífen, assim: (41) 0000-0000; Entendeu? Para facilitar na validação aqui..

Comment: Somente os números inteiro sem mascaras ex: 15954418200

Comment: RESOLVIDO - Não consegui validar por operadora, mas com essa expressão já ajudou e muito... só aceita num de celular de SP já como DDD. /^(?:[11][1-9]9[4-9]|[3-9][1-9][5-9])[0-9]{7,8}$/

Comment: @Rose funciona esse regex pra 11 9 8382 9999? Tirando o 9999, o resto é de um numero TIM existente.

Comment: Sim deve funcionar o num 11983829999 passa na verificação já o num 11933829999 não passará.

Comment: @Rose, você pode implementar esse regex naquela função se quiser também. É só mudar no código.

Comment: Só para complementar os números de celular vão de 6 a 9 e não de 8 a 9 ;)